# Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime det ected an invalid program

Tags: c#, nancy

I bought a new computer recently and uploaded this project to a FTP server and then downloaded it to my new computer but now it is causing this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime det
ected an invalid program.
   at Nancy.Conventions.NancyConventions.<Validate>b__1(Tuple'2 result)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator'1.MoveNext()
   at Nancy.Conventions.NancyConventions.Validate()
   at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase'1.Initialise()
   at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost..ctor(INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper, HostCo
nfiguration configuration, Uri[] baseUris)
   at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost..ctor(Uri baseUri, INancyBootstrapper bootstr
apper, HostConfiguration configuration)
   at PokerServer.Program.startServer() in f:\Projects\Visual Studio\PokerServer
\PokerServer\Program.cs:line 93
   at PokerServer.Program.Main() in f:\Projects\Visual Studio\PokerServer\PokerS
erver\Program.cs:line 23
```

It worked well on the old computer.

I have updated .NET (and all other updates under Windows Update as mentioned in another thread).

I have tried deactive and active "Code optimization" without any problems.

The directory is not the same as before, not sure if that can cause this problem?

I verify my code with peverify and if I understand it correctly everything looks good:

```
F:\Projects\Visual Studio\PokerServer\PokerServer\bin\Debug>peverify PokerServer
.exe /md /il

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework PE Verifier.  Version  4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

All Classes and Methods in PokerServer.exe Verified.
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually compiling the project on the new computer or just running the application?

If you're just running it, did you verify that the application assembly or assemblies are actually identical on both computers? I suggest, you first rule out the option, that something happened during the data transfer.

If you're compiling it, what are you compiling it with? VIsual Studio? Which version?

In any case, the error is not related to the file directory, the application is in. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidprogramexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the exception should only be thrown when the compiled application is invalid (i.e. in case of a bug in the compiler). You can find more info [in this knowledge base article](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/312544). Try running the PEVerify tool and rebuilding the application in debug configurtion as the article suggests.

Comment: VS 12.0.30723.00. I removed and reinstalled Nancy from the Nuget Manager and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the old Nancy dependency and installed it again from Nuget and now it works.